# Get value from a div that was not selected via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have two divs on my page. When a user selects say the first div, I get the hidden value from `userSaved` value from that div, but I'd also like to grab the `userSaved` value from the second div also. I must know that the first value was selected and stored in: saved_id_user_voted_on_val, then for the second value can be stored in something else. It's imperative that the first (selected) value is stored in saved_id_user_voted_on_val.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fl person">
    <div class="maintain_size">
        <input type="hidden" name="userSaved" value="1" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fl person">
    <div class="maintain_size">
        <input type="hidden" name="userSaved" value="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document.body).on('click',"div.person img",function () {
    $(this).parent("div").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        var saved_id_user_who_voted_val = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";
        var saved_id_user_voted_on_val = $(this).parent('div').find('input:hidden');
        var saved_id_user_voted_on_val = saved_id_user_voted_on_val.val();

        var current_div = $(this).parent("div");
        current_div.empty();
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should not have two hidden inputs with the same name - it will cause conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can just conclude from the selected value whether to jump forward or backwards.
If the value will be non integer you can also use the name to differentiate the inputs. Put seeems somehow pointsless in your example code, nevertheless here we go:

```
var selected = $(this).find("input:hidden").val();

if(selected==2)
   var notselected = $(this).prev(".person").find("input:hidden").val();
else
   var notselected = $(this).next(".person").find("input:hidden").val();
```

Or take an array and loop prev() until 1 is reached and next() until NUM_OF_INPUTS is reached.
Take the name to differentiate the inputs and extract the id.

```
var values = new Array();

var selectedInput = $(this).find("input:hidden").attr("name");

var iterDiv = $(this);

for(var j = selectedInput;j>1;j--){
  iterDiv = iterDiv.prev(".person");
  values[j] = iterDiv.find("input:hidden").val();
}
iterDiv = $(this);
for(j = selectedInput;j>NUM_OF_INPUTS;j++){
  //.... get next()
}
```

Comment: The first is no real solution as i kind of stated. At least you should know how many entries exist. There values can be anything as long as you got a unique id per input like in the second code snippet. In your given "binary" example there is no need to get the second value via the DOM, because you can easily tell that its the other value, therefore one guy deleted his answer completely and my first snippet is not practically useful.

Comment: OK you could use an Array to hold all possible outcomes (values) and crawl over the Array to get the index of the selected one. Then u can tell that all other entries are not selected. Then you dont need the name attribute and use the array index (pos) instead. U can preinit this Array on pageload eg.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this solution (a little modification of Sushanth's).

```
var currentDiv = $(this).parent('div');
var saved_id_user_voted_on_val_two = currentDiv.find('input:hidden');
var otherDiv = $('.fl').not(currentDiv);
```